# WebGL game won't go into fullscreen mode on iOS devices

Tags: unity, ios, unity-webgl

I have built my game and hosted it on itch.io. it works well on PC browsers and on the mobile Android browser.

The problem appears when I try to launch it on an iOS phone: the game won't go into full screen (it's supposed to go into it automatically). I added a button that's supposed to switch to full screen but it doesn't respond (the button does work on PC and Android though).

Comment: Which web page template are you using?

Comment: I have tried default, https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/responsive-webgl-template-117308 and this one https://github.com/sno/unity-webgl-responsive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123590/discussion-between-dmgregory-and-fire-cloud).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've encountered a limitation of Safari for iOS, where the Fullscreen API is largely unsupported, being usable only for iPad devices running iOS 12 or later ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#element.requestfullscreen), [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen)).

Safari users on iPhone and iPod devices will be unable to take advantage of true fullscreen functionality, though you can get quite close by prompting users to add your web application to their home screen and applying specific `<meta>` tags to your page. You'll also want your game to span the entire content of the web page. From the great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58759324/15796650):

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Outside of the above, one can reduce the visibility of Safari UI – completely hiding it when in landscape – through certain interactions such as scrolling. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884561/15796650) for more details on how to make clever use of this. (Previously this could be done programmatically, though Apple's patched that option for now.)

---

**Note:** in the past, this functionality could be enabled for iPhone/iPod devices through Safari's advanced settings pane (Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features > Fullscreen API), though this is unfortunately no longer the case.

**Related, somewhat dated (iOS 6) question:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822739